# about validate.js use function

Tags: javascript

```
            "data[ResearchCase][sender_mail]": {
            required: function() { 
                return $("#customer_info").val() =="2";
            },
            email: function() { 
                return $("#customer_info").val() =="2";
            }
        }
        messages: {
         "data[ResearchCase][sender_mail]": {
            required: "must input mail",
            email:"not right email"
         }
        }
```

when customer_info = 1. the required validate is not work,but the email validate always work。
i try wirte like

```
email:function(){retrun false}
or
email:function(){retrun 0}
```

also not work
i also try to delete required validate, but email also work.
where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

hoho, i know why
in the validate.js the email check is not have parameters
the old code

```
        email: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^(((....)))\.?$/i.test(value);
    },
```

the new code

```
        email: function(value, element, param) {
        if (!param) {
            return true;
        }
        return this.optional(element) || /^(((....)))\.?$/i.test(value);
    },
```

when customer_info = 1 ,the eamil validate is not work.
but i have other question,when i wirte eamil:false, the email validate is not work,so what diffrent for

```
email:function(){return false}
```

to

```
email:false
```